# Counting bits in a long long not working as expected

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, tdm-mingw

```
uint64_t bitsToInt64(char *bs) {
    uint64_t r, i;
    r = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        if(bs[i] == 1) 
            r |= 1LL << i;          
    return r;
}

int countBits64(uint64_t i) {
    uint64_t x, t;
    t = 0LL;
    for(x = 0LL; x < 64LL; x++) {
        if(i & (1LL << x))
            t += 1;
    }
    return t;
}

char bits [] = { 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,};

uint64_t mask = bitsToInt64(bits);
int nbits = countBits64(mask);
printf("%d", nbits);
```

The above is printing "1". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output if you do `printf("%ld", mask);` before the last line?

Comment: I don't think this is the only problem, but you should use `1ULL` instead of `1LL`, since a `1 << 63` won't fit into a signed long long. Can you print `mask` so we can determine which function the bug is in?

Comment: printf("%llu", mask); prints 10. But the bitsToInt64() must be working before i am using uint64_t as bitboards for chess pieces and they are all getting/setting correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code below I was able to get the following output

> (0xFF00000000000010) 9

Make sure you use the correct size values. The literal constants need `ULL` so that they match uint64_t and the for loop variables only need to be an int, as well as the return value for `countBits64`.

```
uint64_t bitsToInt64(char *bs) {
    uint64_t r;
    int i;
    r = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        if(bs[i] == 1) 
            r |= 1ULL << i;          
    return r;
}

int countBits64(uint64_t i) {
    int x, t = 0;
    for(x = 0; x < 64; x++) {
        if(i & (1ULL << x))
            t += 1;
    }
    return t;
}

char bits [] = { 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,};

uint64_t mask = bitsToInt64(bits);
int nbits = countBits64(mask);
printf("(0x%016llX) %d",mask, nbits);
```

Comment: Just copied and pasted it again I am still getting what I posted. I am running x64 intel mac and gcc, uint64_t is typedef'd as unsigned long long. I am also able to get the same results with your original code. What compiler, OS, architecture are you on?

Comment: Just updated my last comment, wonder if it some compiler flag or optimization that is causing that for you.

Comment: (0x0000000000000010) 1 with the 0x%016llX but thats still not right. I am doing plan old `gcc input -o output` with no flags

Comment: Here is something fun to do, make them all 1's then if your output looks like 0x00000000FFFFFFFF, your long long is not quite as long as you think.

Comment: OMFG it was because i wasnt importing the a header file in one of the files that uses these functions. No warnings or anything, just a half working function... unbelievable. thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you figured out, were you just missing `<stdint.h>`? I would like to update the answer so someone can find the solution easier.

Answer (score 2):

Your shifting of `1LL`, which is signed, yields [undefined behavior](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT34-C.+Do+not+shift+a+negative+number+of+bits+or+more+bits+than+exist+in+the+operand). Shifting a 64bit **signed** integer by 63 bits is thus allowed to make the compiler do funny things (like [making daemons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)).

The solution is to use `1ULL << x` instead in this case.

See also [this excellent article](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) from an Chris Lattner of LLVM that explains *why* things like this can result in strange behavior.